# Address validation using geocode (GoogleMapAPI) in java

Tags: java

```
URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway&sensor=false&client_id=my_client_id&key=my_key");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Its giving connection refused exception.

Comment: your key and client id is prooper try hitting proper URL in browser and check you are getting response or not?

Comment: Pasting the above URL on browser, is giving back REQUEST_DENIED json..

Comment: @sanbhat he didn't give us his key, if you are using that link the key doesn't match so you get REQUEST_DENIED.

Comment: Do you a have a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually connect:

```
URL url = new URL("yoururl"); 
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

try {
    // open the connection and get results as InputStream.
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();;

    // do more things
} finally {
    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Also you can modify how you encode your URL to avoid errors:

```
private String REQUEST_URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
private String address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway";

URL url = new URL(REQUEST_URL + "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false&client_id=my_client_id&key=my_key"););
```